# Error while loading data into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am trying to load data into MongoDB from Spark below is my code:

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

import com.mongodb.casbah.{WriteConcern => MongodbWriteConcern}
import com.stratio.provider.mongodb._
import MongodbConfig._  

object test  {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[8]")

      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)  

      val test= sqlContext.read.avro("file:///Users\\abhis\\Desktop\\Avro\\test")    // test File
        logger.info("Reading test file")

      // The avro data is stored in a temporary tables 
      test.registerTempTable("test")    //  test temp table

      val targetData = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * From test")  // my code is running fine till here

      // Configuration of MongoDb to save the data into collection
        val targetOutputBuilder = MongodbConfigBuilder(Map(Host -> List("localhost:27017"), Database -> "subs", Collection -> "target", SamplingRatio -> 1.0, WriteConcern -> MongodbWriteConcern.Normal, SplitKey -> "_id", SplitSize -> 8))

        val writeConfig = targetOutputBuilder.build()

        // Writing data into the mongoDb table
        targetData.saveToMongodb(writeConfig)

    }
  }
```

I am running the code in Intellij IDEA and added these jar as dependencies:

- casbah-commons_2.10-2.8.0
- casbah-core_2.10-2.8.0
- casbah-core_2.10-2.8.0
- mongo-java-driver-2.13.0
- spark-mongodb-core-0.8.7

I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.MongoClient
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient$.apply(MongoClient.scala:176)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.MongodbClientFactory$.createClient(MongodbClientFactory.scala:43)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.writer.MongodbWriter.<init>(MongodbWriter.scala:40)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.writer.MongodbBatchWriter.<init>(MongodbBatchWriter.scala:32)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.MongodbDataFrame$$anonfun$saveToMongodb$1.apply(mongodbFunctions.scala:61)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.MongodbDataFrame$$anonfun$saveToMongodb$1.apply(mongodbFunctions.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/05/15 22:13:57 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 18)
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes
    at com.mongodb.Bytes.<clinit>(Bytes.java:219)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<clinit>(Mongo.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient$.apply(MongoClient.scala:176)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.MongodbClientFactory$.createClient(MongodbClientFactory.scala:43)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.writer.MongodbWriter.<init>(MongodbWriter.scala:40)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.writer.MongodbBatchWriter.<init>(MongodbBatchWriter.scala:32)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.MongodbDataFrame$$anonfun$saveToMongodb$1.apply(mongodbFunctions.scala:61)
    at com.stratio.provider.mongodb.MongodbDataFrame$$anonfun$saveToMongodb$1.apply(mongodbFunctions.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried your code with slight modifications, it works.
I did not test your exact setup (dependency versions), that is way off from my setup to test. If you can change your versions, this might help.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.stratio.datasource._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.schema._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.writer._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.config.MongodbConfig._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.stratio.datasource.util.Config._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.config.MongodbConfigBuilder

/**
 * Using https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB
 */
object ToMongoDB {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ToMongoDB")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val avroInput = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/spark_learning/avro/")


    val targetOutputBuilder = MongodbConfigBuilder(
      Map(Host -> List("localhost:27017"),
        Database -> "test",
        Collection -> "target",
        SamplingRatio -> 1.0,
        WriteConcern -> "normal", //changed from MongodbWriteConcern.Normal to "normal"
        SplitKey -> "_id",
        SplitSize -> 8))

    val writeConfig =  targetOutputBuilder.build()
    avroInput.saveToMongodb(writeConfig)
  }

}
```

I added these dependecnies in the buid.sbt file

```
val spark_mongodb = "com.stratio" % "spark-mongodb" % "0.8.0"
val spark_mongodb_stratio = "com.stratio.datasource" % "spark-mongodb_2.10" % "0.11.1"
val spark_avro = "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "1.0.0"
libraryDependencies += spark_mongodb,
libraryDependencies += spark_mongodb_stratio,
libraryDependencies += spark_avro
```